# Distribution of a Minimum of iid random variables to a power

Tags: probability, distributions, order-statistics

Assume that I have $Z_{1},Z_{2},\dots,Z_{N}$ independent and identically distributed random draws following distribution $F(z)$ which are positive-valued. Define random variables $Y = \min_{i \in N} \left\{Z_{i}\right\}$ and $W=Y^{-c}, c >0$. I am interested in computing the cdf of W.

We know that

$Pr(Y \leq y) = 1 - \left[1-F(y) \right]^{N}$

Is it correct to say that,

\begin{align*}
Pr(W \leq w) &= Pr (Y^{-c} \leq w ) \\
&=Pr(\frac{1}{Y^{c}} \leq w ) \\
&=Pr(\frac{1}{w} \leq Y^{c} ) \\
&=Pr(w^{-\frac{1}{c}} \leq Y ) \\
&=1-Pr( Y \leq  w^{-\frac{1}{c}} ) \\
&=1-1+\left[1-F(w^{-\frac{1}{c}}) \right]^{N}=\left[1-F(w^{-\frac{1}{c}}) \right]^{N}
\end{align*}
?

Comment: Do you know that $Y>0$?

Comment: Yes, I am sorry. All the $Z_{i}$ are positive. Edited